# Using redirectTo in a nested <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have this very simple router config:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MiddleComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: './task-queue',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'task-queue',
        component: TestComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7sxdf?file=app%2Fapp.routing.ts

Where `MiddleComponent`'s template is just `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

I'd expect that after page load I should be redirected to `task-queue` but I'm not. I can see the `MiddleComponent` is rendered but `TestComponent` isn't.

Comment: For starters I would say that children routers woud be best defined in separate router modules

Comment: @An-droid That's completely unrelated to this question.

Comment: It may seems so, but dealing with a router issue in angular the way you implement it can change drastically the way it behaves

Answer (score 2):

Need to add another path with redirect property for test-queue.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/task-queue' ,
    pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '', component: MiddleComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/task-queue',pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'task-queue', component: TestComponent }
    ] 
  }
];
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjhcvd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I don't want to navigate myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this changing `pathMatch` to **prefix** for the parent route and removing the `./` in the child route

([Angular documentation for redirecting](https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes))

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MiddleComponent,
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'task-queue',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'task-queue',
        component: TestComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

I got that solution from reading https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14692 (this does not seem to only apply to lazy routes)

[Modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6tsck?file=app/app.routing.ts)

But the solution if redirecting straight away to `/task-queue` from the parent works too