# Make Nested route default route - [Angular]

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my Angular-6 project, I want a nested route to be the default route. That means if the user hits "**localhost:4200**" in browser he'll be redirected to "**localhost:4200/dashboard/headlines**". I wrote below route configuration, but it is not working.
 1. what am I doing wrong? 
 2. Is it possible to implement the same for lazy loading module?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: NewsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/headlines', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'headlines', component: HeadLinesComponent },
      { path: 'detail', component: DeatilNewsComponent }
    ]
  }
]
```

news.component.html

```
<div>News Work</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: try removing backslash, redirectTo: '/dashboard' => redirectTo: 'dashboard' and redirectTo: '/headlines' => redirectTo: 'headlines'

Answer (score 1):

Here is your [**Working Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-route-is-default-route)

Modify your `app.routing.ts` to the code below:~

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NewsComponent } from './news.component';
import { HeadLinesComponent } from './head-lines.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: NewsComponent,
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'headlines', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'headlines', component: HeadLinesComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

[*Exact duplicate here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989400/using-redirectto-in-a-nested-router-outlet)

[**Check here for more on Lazy loading the default child route**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48878754/how-to-load-child-route-by-default-with-lazy-loading-in-angular-2)

[Check out the official Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your routes to this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: NewsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'headlines', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'headlines', component: HeadLinesComponent }
    ]
  }
]
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tklgdg)